# Même si les gars sont / étaient surpris

Tags: sens, conditions

Bonjour,

Avant, les amis de A ont été surpris à plusieurs reprises par son attitude et ils le lui ont dit. À présent, ils quittent la cour du temple, mais A souhaite y rester, et son choix devrait étonner ses amis.

> Cette fois, même si les gars **sont** surpris, ils ne le laissent pas
> paraitre.
>
> Cette fois, même si les gars **étaient** surpris, ils ne le laisseraient
> pas paraitre.

La deuxième phrase signifie qu'en réalité, ils ne sont pas surpris, mais que l'on pourrait s'imaginer qu'ils sont surpris. Est-ce qu'elle peut aussi avoir un deuxième sens, introduire une hypothèse *S'ils étaient surpris...* ou elle ne représente qu'une condition irréelle ?

Comment: Le « cette fois » me gêne dans le 2. « Cette fois, même si les gars étaient surpris, ils ne le laissèrent pas paraître. » Ou alors  « même si les gars étaient surpris, ils ne le laisseraient pas paraître » et on est dans l’irréel. Cette-fois implique qu'on est dans le réel. À moins que quelque chose m'échappe dans ce que tu veux dire...

Comment: @None, merci, nous sommes dans le réel, mais en même temps c'est une hypothèse, je vais ajouter le contexte à ma question.

Comment: Le conditionnel sert aussi à exprimer un futur dans le passé.

Comment: @None Oui, mais la narration est au présent. J'ai ajouté une explication, j'espère que c'est plus clair maintenant.

Comment: Je n'arrive pas à le sentir comme ça. Et de toutes façons la phrase 1 aussi exprime   « qu'ils ne sont pas surpris, mais que l'on pourrait s'imaginer qu'ils sont surpris ».

Comment: @None D'accord, merci, j'écrirai donc la 1ère phrase.

Comment: J'ai l'impression que "même si" dans la première phrase sous-entend un peu trop qu'ils sont surpris. Si tu veux que ce soit une hypothèse plus évidente, tu peux simplement retirer le "même": Cette fois, si les gars sont surpris, ils ne le laissent pas paraître.

Comment: @Simon C'est ce que je voulais dire, merci ! En russe, dans cette structure, j'employerais "même", c'est ce qui m'a déconcerté.